# Xamarin android app throws object not set when calling api

Tags: android, xamarin, async-await, task

So i have android app that makes several requests to api using following structure. Note that this works in iOS and this appeared to start happening after updating xamarin forms.

```
public async Task<Rootobject> GetData()
{
    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url); //throws exception here. See screenshot
    }
}
```

[image]

This works fine for all my requests except for one and the only difference is that this one is called from within a task factory like following:

```
tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(async()=>
{
    var data = await GetData();
}));
```

And invoked like following:

```
Task.WhenAll(tasks).ContinueWith(t =>
{   
     IsBusy = false;              
}).GetAwaiter();
```

The part that really has me confused is that this works as expected in iOS. Does anyone have any idea what i can do to get past this?

Comment: Do you mean it throws a NullReference exception?  Which specific line?  What is the stack trace?  Is the code you posted complete?  Because you are not showing any return values, you are just assigning results to local variables and throwing them away.

Comment: Yes updated post to show error and what line it occurs. I don't have option to not use Xamarin. I tried to only post what the issue is and not have code on it that isn't relevant.

Comment: Please provide a  MCVE (minimal, complete, verifiable example as I am unable to reproduce this issue with the code provided. See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve
Your code as is is faulty in that you do not return anything from your Task<RootObject> method so that would not even compile. 
Also need to know if the issue occurs when the is only one Task in "tasks" variable, or if it occurs only with multiple Tasks in "tasks". Also Task.Run is recommended over Task.Factory.StartNew unless you need more fine grained control over Task creation options, etc.

Comment: I was not able to produce mvce. Turned out i was on a wild goose chase and issue ended up being https://github.com/alexrainman/CarouselView/issues/557

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the api was not issue at all even though it seemed like it because that is where debugger would blow up but turned out issue was  https://github.com/alexrainman/CarouselView/issues/557 and is still an issue. My work around is to use custom carousel view when android instead of plugin. Hope this helps someone not spend nearly two days on like i did.